# How to generate a random, unique mobile number in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have a requirement to generate a Random mobile number and input it in my subsequent request. During load test when running using multiple users ( ~1k users), *how should I ensure the uniqueness of it across all my users?*

I am using a groovy script for this task that generates a mobile number randomly.

(int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (9000000000 - 9000020000)) + 9000020000

I know that I can pre-generate the random mobile numbers and send as parameters. But I don't want to use this approach of static/parameterized data.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot guarantee the "uniqueness" if you're talking about random.

You could do something like:

1. Get the [current timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())
2. Get the [current virtual user number](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum--)
3. Get the [current iteration](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration--)
4. Put everything together

Example code:

```
def timestamp = System.nanoTime()
def currentUser = ctx.getThreadNum()
def iteration = vars.getIteration()

def randomValue = timestamp as String + currentUser + iteration

vars.put('randomValue', randomValue)
```

More information on the aforementioned JMeter API shorthands: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion dmitri, still figuring out for this task

Answer (score 1):

If there is a formatting requirement on the mobile number you could prefix a timestamp and limit the output to the remaining number of digits like so:

Note: ***Mddmmsss*** will add 8 random digits to the prefix 077 (total of 11 digits like a standard UK phone number)

```
077${__time(Mddmmsss,)}
```

output exmaple:

> 07792203003

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Java faker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) to generate the random number.

```
import com.github.javafaker.service.FakeValuesService
import com.github.javafaker.service.RandomService

FakeValuesService fakeValuesService

fakeValuesService = new FakeValuesService(new Locale("en-AU"), new RandomService());

String prefixMobile = "04"
String mobileNumber  = fakeValuesService.regexify(String.format("%s\\d{8}", prefixMobile))
vars.put("mobileNumber",mobileNumber)
```

You will have to download the jar file, place the jar inside JMETER_HOME/bin folder and restart the JMeter to ensure the jar is available for your test.

Comment: Hi Janesh, Does this work while running using distributed load test while we use multiple VMs as Slaves?

Comment: Hi @George , It will work in the distributed environment.. You will have to copy the Java-Faker jar file to each slave. I would recommend the solution given by  Dimitri. It's simple and will work without any dependency.