# JMeter: How to send multiple unique json body?

Tags: rest, post, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have written a REST API and now my requirement is to load test it for 1k calls or something. Problem is the request json has an unique attribute - **Cnumber** which needs to be changed for every request.

json request:

**{
"Code": "WEB",
"Pfix": null,
"Name": "Ronaldo",
"Cnumber": "C7"
}**

how can I make this request for 1K users concurrently with **Cnumber** changes in every request?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328356/generate-random-number-variables-in-jmeter/45328753#45328753

Comment: @user7294900 can I also use it in Body Data like {"Cnumber": ${__Random(0000,9999)}}, something like this. request body is a lengthy json.

Comment: See (how-to-generate-a-random-unique-mobile-number)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69106489/how-to-generate-a-random-unique-mobile-number-in-jmeter] for details to generate a random, unique number.

Comment: `${__Random(0000,9999)}}, ` shall not be used. It generates a random number but not a unique number.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. Incrementing number can be generated using [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function like:

   ```
   { "Code": "WEB", "Pfix": null, "Name": "Ronaldo", "Cnumber": "${__counter(FALSE,)}" }
   ```
2. Random number can be generated using [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function

   ```
   { "Code": "WEB", "Pfix": null, "Name": "Ronaldo", "Cnumber": "${__Random(1,2147483647,)}" }
   ```
3. Random alphanumeric string can be generated using [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function like:

   ```
   { "Code": "WEB", "Pfix": null, "Name": "Ronaldo", "Cnumber": "${__RandomString(2,abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}" }
   ```
4. Current thread number: [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function

   ```
   { "Code": "WEB", "Pfix": null, "Name": "Ronaldo", "Cnumber": "${__threadNum}" }
   ```
5. GUID-like structure: [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function

   ```
   { "Code": "WEB", "Pfix": null, "Name": "Ronaldo", "Cnumber": "${__UUID}" }
   ```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: thank you , this was useful , what about if we also want other fields to be changed with new request like a different Name, Email Id ? have to config it in csv ?

Comment: Depending on whether you want  to use random data or a pre-defined data set you either could go for the aforementioned [__RandomString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) or [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or use i.e. [Faker library](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) from [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a timestamp...

```
{ "Code": "WEB", "Pfix": null, "Name": "Ronaldo", "Cnumber": "C${__time}" }
```

[Cnumber with timestamp example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWxea.png)

Comment: thank you , this was useful , what about if we also want other fields to be changed with new request like a different Name, Email Id ? have to config it in csv ?

Comment: Could use RandomString for email, set to say "10" length using any letter of the alphabet...
Email example = ${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)}@gmail.com
Output example = aimcwyoshb@gmail.com